# Linux Kernel: Targeted Latency vs Minimum Granularity

Tags: process, kernel, scheduler, timeslots

In context of CFS Scheduler of Linux Kernel what are the most important differences between **Targeted Latency** and **Minimum Granularity**.

Or how do we define **Targeted Latency** and **Minimum Granularity**.

- Mathematical explanation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

> how do we define Targeted Latency and Minimum Granularity.

From "Linux kernel development" by Robert Love:

1)

> CFS sets a target for its approximation of the “infinitely small”
>   scheduling duration in perfect multitasking. This target is called the
>   **targeted latency**.

2)

> Note as the number of runnable tasks approaches infinity, the
>   proportion of allotted processor and the assigned timeslice approaches
>   zero. As this will eventually result in unacceptable switching costs,
>   CFS imposes a floor on the timeslice assigned to each process.This
>   floor is called **the minimum granularity**.

So, targeted latency is the period in which all run queue tasks are scheduled at least once. And the minimum granularity is the minimum time a task will be be allowed to run on CPU before being pre-empted out.

References:

- http://oakbytes.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/linux-scheduler-cfs-and-latency/
- http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-tuning_sd_draft/cha.tuning.taskscheduler.html
- http://www.google.ru/search?q=Robert+Love+Linux+Kernel+development&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=qZcQVIyeCMaA8Ab7wYGYBw

Comment: The 1st link has been very useful.